# How to use my calendar from davmail in Emacs

Tags: emacs, calendar

In my company, we use exchange server, so I setup a davmail server to act as a proxy. Now I can use mu4e in emacs to get/write emails through smtp and imap protocol.
But I want to see the calendar in emacs. davmail supports Caldav, but I am new to both emacs calendar and caldav. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is [org-caldav](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav) but I haven't used it personally.

I typically keep around Thunderbird instead of other solutions to ensure that all the calendar updates are synced properly.

I've tried looking up old versions of the standalone calendar application Sunbird, but I run into library issues that I didn't have time to solve under Linux.

I also don't know how convenient/performant caldav would be if you've got a huge number of meetings.

At this time my recommendation would be to rely on an external application.